# How to access member function with iterator in C++ std::set

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

I am trying to iterate over a C++ std::set and access a member function. But my following code is not working.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
class A;

std::set<A> m_vector;
std::set<A>::iterator iter = m_vector.begin();

class  A
{
  public:
    int age;
    A()
    {
        cout << "enter age" << endl;
        cin >> age;
    }

    int getAge() 
    {
       return age;
    }
  private:

};
void addNewVoter()
{
    m_vector.insert(A());
}
int main()
{
    addNewVoter();
    addNewVoter();
    addNewVoter();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m_vector.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << (*iter)->getAge(); /* Here is the mistake. I can't invoke this.*/
        iter++;
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I invoke member function with iterator?

Comment: `iter->getAge()` or `(*iter).getAge()`

Comment: Changing the vector with `insert` or `push_back` invalidates the iterator.

Comment: `std::set<A> m_vector;` and it's global, wow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize `iter` when you are ready to traverse. Also, access member(s) by either `iter->getAge()` or `(*iter).getAge()`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

class A;

std::set<A> m_vector;
std::set<A>::iterator iter;

/* other codes */

int main()
{
    addNewVoter();
    addNewVoter();
    addNewVoter();

    iter = m_vector.begin();

    while( iter != m_vector.end() )
    {
        cout << iter->getAge();
        iter++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Three changes are required in your code snippet. std::set internally implementing a  red black binary tree and it required an operator overloading for comparison.

So you class should have an additional function:

```
 bool operator <(const A& other) const
 {
      return age < other.age;
 }
```

Then while you call getAge() function system passing a const object of A, so your getAge function should be a const function.

```
int getAge() const
             ^^^^^
{
   return age;
}
```

Third one, you should invoke the getAge function either using one of these syntax. `(*iter).getAge()` or `iter->getAge()`; dont mix it up.

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7eaf71ca41de226d)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit first:**

Let's say you at least know how to invoke that member function through pointer. The answer is `iter->getAge()` or `(*iter).getAge()` - in the comments.

---

Then you're doing this:

```
std::set<A> my_set;
auto it = my_set.begin();
// some inserts
std::cout << it->getAge() << std::endl;
```

which is undefined behaviour. You don't dereference *begin* iterator acquired originally from an empty container.

Just use this, instead:

```
for (auto it = my_set.begin(); it != my_set.end(); ++it)
    std::cout << it->getAge() << std::endl;
```

or the range-based `for`...

---

<sub>As you can see, I refused to use your naming conventions because they're bad and misleading.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for the response but this doesn't work ...  i want to add first 3 objects in the set and after that i want to take function getAge() through
iterator